# Faster way to compare string part of a multi type vector with one type vector and erase duplicate

Tags: c++, string, vector, string-comparison

I want to compare string parts of the vectors below and erase the duplicate as fast as possible.

```
using namespace std;

vector<string> v1;
vector<pair<string, int>> v2;
```

I've tried `find_if` lambda, which seems to be slightly faster than nested `for` loops.

Example data:

```
+--------+------------+
| index  |     v1     |
+--------+------------+
| 0      | apple      |
+--------+------------+
| 1      | watermelon |
+--------+------------+
| 2      | cherry     |
+--------+------------+
| 3      | tomato     |
+--------+------------+
| 4      | cucumber   |
+--------+------------+
| .      | .          |
+--------+------------+
| .      | .          |
+--------+------------+
| 419776 | lettuce    |
+--------+------------+

+--------+---------------------+
| index  |         v2          |
+--------+------------+--------+
|        |    first   | second |
+--------+------------+--------+
| 0      | pear       | 345    |
+--------+------------+--------+
| 1      | apple      | 85     |
+--------+------------+--------+
| 2      | strawberry | 1912   |
+--------+------------+--------+
| 3      | grape      | 54     |
+--------+------------+--------+
| 4      | peach      | 90     |
+--------+------------+--------+
| .      | .          | .      |
+--------+------------+--------+
| .      | .          | .      |
+--------+------------+--------+
| 21803  | pineapple  | 100    |
+--------+------------+--------+
```

Desired outcome:

As you can see, `apple` matches exactly the same in either vectors. So i want v1 to erase the duplicate.

Tested methods:

```
for (auto itr1 = v1.begin(); itr1 != v1.end(); ++itr1)
    for (auto itr2 = v2.begin(); itr2 != v2.end(); ++itr2)
        if (*itr1 == itr2->first)
            v1.erase(itr1);
```

It took around 35 seconds for the nested `for` loops.

```
auto itr = v1.begin();
for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [&itr, &v1, v2](const auto& s)
{
    ++itr;
    if (find_if(v2.begin(), v2.end(), [s](const auto& sV) { return s == sV.first; }) != v2.end())
        v1.erase(itr);
});
```

It took around 31 seconds for this one.

Comment: I see no `apple` in the second vector.  Second, maybe you should be considering a different data structure.  Third, where and how are you getting your timing information?

Comment: Please [stop posting duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552106/fast-way-to-compare-string-part-of-a-multi-type-vector-with-one-type-vector). If you did not get any good answers to your original question, deleting it and reposting a duplicate copy of it is not going to make it any more likely that it will be answered this time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of a deleted question that was posted 2 hours ago by the same poster.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It was deleted because you didn't understand nor wait for more information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just corrected. As for timing, i used ctime.

Comment: What I mean by time is we have no idea the amount of data, whether you are timing a release build (not a debug build), the compiler, etc.  You can't just post code, say it takes x seconds, and that's it.  Second, of course an `O(N*N)` approach takes more time -- use a different data structure to store the information.

Comment: I understood everything fully, and I wasn't even in the group who voted to close your first question, so I have no idea what you're referring to.

Comment: I voted to close your original question. You edited it to add your code, but then deleted it 2 min later. Undelete it, and I'll vote to reopen it, but after you've added some information, e.g. a [mre], the data set you're using, and the flags you're using to compile the code.

Comment: @cigien Let that one be removed, there is an answer here anyways.

Comment: Even if there is an answer, you still have not posted the necessary information that confirms your claim of this routine taking 30+ seconds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm just looking what's best for vectors. And yes we have no idea the amount of data, it's changing constantly. The more it is, the more it will take eventually.

Comment: Regardless of there being an answer, I'm going to vote to close this question until the information I mentioned above is added.

Comment: The answer here does fix the bug in your code, but it is unlikely to result in any better performance.

Comment: This really depends on the sizes of the vectors. Your solution is O(N*M) You may get both vector sizes. Sort smaller vector. Then go through the bigger vector, doing binary search of each element of the bigger vector in a smaller vector. If not found, copy to the output. The overall complexity of this algorithm is O((M+N)*Log(N)) where N is smaller size.

Comment: *And yes we have no idea the amount of data* -- So you don't know how much data you're dealing with?  You should know, since all you need to do is output`vector.size()` for each one of the vectors before all of this processing is done.

Comment: I concur with @dgrandm that the algorithm he sketches in his comment is the fastest possible approach to the problem, he should expand that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<string> v1{ "apple", "watermelon", "cherry", "cucumber" };
vector<pair<string, int>> v2{ {"pear",345},{"apple",85},{"strawberry",1912},{"grape",54},{"peach",90} };

struct HASH {
public:
    size_t operator()(const pair<string, long long>& p) const {
        return hash<string>()(p.first);
    }
};

struct EQUAL {
public:
    bool operator()(const pair<string, long long>& p1, const pair<string, long long>& p2) const {
        return p1.first == p2.first ? true : false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<pair<string, long long>> V1Unique;
    unordered_set<pair<string, long long>, HASH, EQUAL> s;

    for (auto itr = v2.begin(); itr != v2.end(); ++itr)
        s.insert(make_pair(itr->first, itr-v2.begin()));
    for (auto itr = v1.begin(); itr != v1.end(); ++itr)
        s.insert(make_pair(*itr, v2.size()+itr-v1.begin()));

    V1Unique.assign(s.begin(), s.end());

    sort(V1Unique.begin(), V1Unique.end(),
        [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.second > b.second; });

    for (int i = 0; i < v2.size(); ++i)
        if (!V1Unique.empty())
            V1Unique.pop_back();

    for (auto itr = V1Unique.begin(); itr != V1Unique.end(); ++itr)
        cout << itr->first << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think this is the fastest way.

Comment: wrong logic (what if there are elements in v2 which are not in v1. if this is not possible, you haven't said it in the Q) and bad performance (due to the reallocations).

Comment: Sorry, but you again have undefined behaviour in the code. Once you call erase on a vector you invalidate iterators. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase Read about erase-remove idiom, V1Unique.erase(itr); line where it should be used

Comment: @dgrandm Oh yeah, i forgot about that. Now it's ok.

Comment: @dgrandm About the invalidation; i could just use returned iterator `itr = V1Unique.erase(itr);` to prevent undefined behaviour, which i think is much simpler.